# Can I use multiple functions in substitute string in vim

Tags: vim

I want to extract information from file path and use it as part of substitute string, racked my mind, tried many times and only to found the follwing works

```
let spd = split(expand('%:p'),"/")
%s/to_be_replaced/\=spd[-2]/g
```

I want to merge the two commands into one

```
%s/to_be_replaced/\=split(expand('%:p',"/"))[-2]/g
```

but it doesn't work. Since I am working with multiple files in tab mode, the two commmands method is actually quite inconvenient. Moreover, it doesn't fulfill the requirement since

```
%s/to_be_replaced/some_string\=spd[-2]more_string/g
```

is also wrong. So I am wondering if there is a solution or a quicker way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try other delimit (such as `@`)

```
%s@to_be_replaced@\=split(expand('%:p'),'/')[-2]@g
```

If you want to embed expr insider string:

```
%s@to_be_replaced@\=printf('some_string%smore_string', spd[-2])@g
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Alternative

Unless you invoke this for multiple buffers (`:bufdo` et al.), your expression is **constant** for the buffer. You can therefore insert it literally in the command line via `<C-r>=`:

```
:%s/to_be_replaced/<C-r>=split(expand('%:p'),"/")[-2]<CR>/g
```

#### Explanation of your problem

The reason why your original attempt doesn't work is explained at `:help sub-replace-expression`:

> Be careful: The separation character must not appear in the expression!
>   Consider using a character like "@" or ":".

As kev has pointed out, you can just use any other single-byte character, but not an alphanumeric character, '\', '"' or '|'.

Comment: Thank you for your nice reply!